# Inverting a Font?

Tags: windows, font

How can I invert a font like so:

[image]

This is my own `.ttf` font, I can edit it. The image that I posted was inverted manually by me. I am searching for a way to invert automatically all characters of the font.

Invert means: convert 1 to 0 and 1 to 0. Which will convert the filled (black) parts to transparent and the transparent parts to filled.

I want a "Font Invertor" software or a simple way to achieve this. Does High-Logic FontCreator do this?

Comment: IMHO your inversion is incorrect. What about the corners outside the "circle"? Shouldn't they be black? If not, how can a software decide about it?